# Is the set $H= \{x^2: x \in \Bbb R\}$ an open or closed set?

Tags: real-analysis

> Is the set $H= \{x^2: x \in \Bbb R\}$  open or closed in $\Bbb R$ ?

I believe this set is open since every arbitrary neighborhood contains an element of our set. $x$ is an element of the reals. I'm not sure if it is closed. How can we prove it either way?

Comment: Do you mean $H=\{x^2: x \in \Bbb R\}$ with usual metric?

Comment: What do you mean by $H=\{x^2\}$? If you write like this, it is a set with a single point. And your definition of openess is wrong. A set $A$ is open if every point of $A$ has a neighborhood contained in $A$. That's different of an arbitrary neighborhood of the space containing always points of $A$.

Comment: @ChinnapparajR yes, you are correct.

Comment: @mikermike, if you mean  $H=\{x^2:x\in \mathbb{R}\}$, then $H=\mathbb{R}$, and your set is both open and closed.

Comment: @CélioAugusto:  isn't $H=[0,\infty) ? $

Comment: @J.W.Tanner of course. That was a silly mistake

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition about open set is wrong! For definition, see this [wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_set) link.

Here $$H=\{x^2: x \in \Bbb R\}=[0, \infty)$$ so it is closed, since it's complement $(-\infty, 0)$ is open. H is not open, since any nbd of zero does not entirely contained in H

The other way to see H is not open as follows:

Since it is already closed, so if in addition it were open, then the real line becomes a disconnected set, which is false.

Comment: The disconnected set part is good. I didn't think of that. +1

Answer (score 1):

It should be clear that $H$ is the set of nonnegative reals. In other words, $H=[0,\infty)$. For any $\varepsilon>0$, a neighborhood of radius $\varepsilon$ around $x=0$ is partially outside $H$. This means that $H$ is not open since for a set to be open, by definition, all points in the set must live within a neighborhood which is entirely contained in the set.

You can use this same argument to show that $H^c$ (the complement of $H$ in $\mathbb{R}$) is open, hence $H$ is closed. Equivalently, what are the limit points of $H$? A set is closed if it contains all of its limit points, and exploring this method would be a good exercise.